# ORDER BY DATETIME in Spring Boot API

Tags: sql, spring-boot, datetime, sql-order-by

I'm struggling to order my JSON list by datetime. Here's what I did

```
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date postedAt;
```

And this is the query as it shown below from the repo :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Post u  WHERE u.supervisor_id = ?1 
                ORDER BY convert(datetime,u.postedAt,121) ASC", nativeQuery = true)
```

List findPostsBySupervisorId(Long id);

but it's not working. What should I do to get my list ordered?

Comment: Why you don't use just `ORDER BY u.postedAt ASC` ?

Comment: it also shows the same result :(

Comment: Do you have any error or something?

Answer (score 1):

I am not big fan of `@Query`, there are better ways, e.g. repository methods like `findAllByOrderByPostedAtAsc`, but if you have to, then what is reason not using just `order by u.postedAt` ?

Comment: I've  tested findAllByOrderByPostedAtAsc ,  and it's not working